# Virtuemart 2.0 and user register

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, joomla1.7

I'm using Joomla 1.7.3 and Virtuemart 2.0, everything works except the registration of users, in previous virtuemart this worked by default, but now I can not register new users, some clue about the problem?

Comment: We need some clue's as to what you're doing and what's happening to be able to help you.

Comment: Virtuemart installed normally, and go to the account maintenance page, and when I fill the data and try to register the user the system tells me this Error: Please enter your name. This is weird I fill all fields in the form.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening.

1. In VM 2.0 there is some XML missing that allows you to specify a link to a registration form - if you use the account maintenance option it gets a slightly different page (see [this thread on the VirtueMart 2.0 forum](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=96215.msg317602#msg317602)). This is already fixed in the prerelease version 2.0.1b and hides some unwanted fields.

   To link to the correct page you should use a Joomla! menu type of `System Links -> External URL` and set the **Link** field to:

   `/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=user&layout=editaddress`
2. The "Please enter your name." means that the field is defined in VM2's configuration as **Required**. I believe the problem occurs because neither the Account Maintenance or the link I provided above give the user a chance to enter a user name.  The work around is to point them to a standard Joomla! registration page and then when they checkout they can complete the rest of their details.

   (In VM2 shoppers are standard Joomla! users so this is a perfectly acceptable way around it).

Answer (score 0):

with the link you told me the problem is still happening, so I was to comment the line of user.php that making the validation in the method check()

```
if (trim($this->name) == '') {
        $this->setError(JText::_('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_PLEASE_ENTER_YOUR_NAME'));
        return false;
    }
```

the value for this->name is empty, why??? with this lines comment, i can register and login on virtuemart....